# Middle click with two-finger tap on touchpad

Tags: xorg, linux-mint, touchpad

In Linux Mint the default action when tapping the touchpad with two fingers is a right click. How can I change this to middle click?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're using an synaptics touchpad, you can use `synclient` to fine-tune the config.

Use following commands for middleclick on 2 fingers and right on 3 fingers:

```
synclient TapButton2=2
synclient TapButton3=3
```

The problem: you have to use these commands after each startup, so you should put them in an startup script.

I bet there is a way to configure this permanently, but I'm using it this way and it works fine for me.

Answer (score 1):

This is managed by the **`synaptics`** input for Xorg and as such, can be configured in your `/etc/X11/xorg.conf`. Open up `man synaptics` to see the options for that driver.

The setting to permanently bind two finger tap as a middle-click is

```
Option "ClickFinger2" 3
```

Since `3` is commonly the number of middle mouse button.