# Remove touchpad two-finger right-click

Tags: ubuntu, gnome-shell, touchpad

After the latest updates (I assume to `gnome-shell`), my touchpad right-click switched from "pressing bottom right zone" to "two-finger tap anywhere".

I find this confusing and I want to restore my right-clicks to pressing the bottom-right part of the touchpad.

What I tried so far:

- `Settings -> Mouse & touchpad` but no luck
- [Middle click with two-finger tap on touchpad](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/27450/middle-click-with-two-finger-tap-on-touchpad) but I didn't have `synclient` installed. After installing, I get: `Couldn't find synaptics properties. No synaptics driver loaded?`

Any ideas?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I came across https://askubuntu.com/questions/999631/ubuntu-17-10-disable-touchpad-bottom-right-corner-right-click

That pointed me in the right direction.

Running

```
gsettings list-recursively org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.touchpad
```

lists all touchpad settings. I'm only interested in

```
gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.touchpad click-method
```

which at the moment returns `fingers`.

Now I just needed to know what are the valid options I can set this key to.
After some digging, I found `range`

```
gsettings range org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.touchpad click-method
```

which returns

> enum
>   'default'
>   'none'
>   'areas'
>   'fingers'

Finally, running this solved it:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.touchpad click-method areas
```

Answer (score 2):

This can be done in the GUI as well, if you like (at least, it can as of Ubuntu 19.04). Use the Ubuntu Software app to install the "GNOME Tweaks" app. Then launch GNOME Tweaks and in the "Keyboard and Mouse" section, click your desired setting under "Mouse Click Emulation". In this case, the asker wants the "Area" option, but you can also choose "Fingers" if you prefer the two-finger right click.

The GNOME Tweaks app edits the same setting mentioned in the accepted answer, it just lets you do it without the command line if you're more comfortable using a GUI.

Comment: On 22.04, if I pick "Area", it doesn't disable the 2 fingers thing